# How to automatically close an app when I shut down the mac?

Tags: shutdown, applications

My father would always scold me that so many applications are open when he turns on the computer which he says consumes computer memory. I always forget to close the app by right -clicking>quit Is there any way to automatically close an app when shutting down? When I searched at google. They talked about iCalendar, but it was too confusing so I came here to ask.

Comment: Apps do close down when you log out - are you and your father using the same login, sounds like you should use separate ones - also as OSX uses virtual memory leaving apps open should not affect users' use much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all apps will be closed when shutting down, simply because the computer will be turned off. Just to be sure: Shutting down means: Turning the computer off.

However the behavior after rebooting differs depending on the operation system version you are using. If you are running *Lion* or *Mountain Lion* there is a *feature* that allows to **automatically  restart** all open applications after rebooting/start up. In *Mountain Lion* you will be asked before the computer shuts down if you want the applications to be restarted after reboot. Just uncheck the checkbox.

[image]

If you're confusing *shutting down* with *standby* and/or *sleep mode* you will have no built-in way to solve it (but an AppleScript may help). But at least I can provide you with a shortcut: Pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>Q</kbd> will "completely" close an application. You can use this shortcut instead of right clicking the dock icon to close the app.

Comment: Lion had the same option in the shutdown dialog box, but it always defaulted to checked (and I believe at one stage it just flat out didnt work)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac os x lion or later, which you apparently do, you can just uncheck the "reopen windows when logging back in" when the log-out or shut down menu comes up!

This way your perviously opened app won't open again!

If they do... you have certain applications set as a* login item
this is fixed by opening system pref - users & groups - login items and review that list.